# Are there any more informal ways of saying "thanks" than "gracias"?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, coloquialismos, cortesía

In English I might say *thanks* instead of *thank you*.  In Portuguese I'd say *valeu* as an informal *obrigado* or, for a big thank you to a friend, you can also informally say *obrigadão* (the augmentative).

Does Spanish any similar, informal thank-yous?  Perhaps regional or slang words.

Comment: I've read *graciñas* (diminutive à la gallega), but I don't know if it's actually used in real life even in Galicia; probably more of an internet slang thing.

Comment: I believe _gracias_ is both formal and informal. Could you provide an example on a case where you would need such expression? I can think on some wordings, only that they may not sound informal but a bit rude.

Comment: From personal experience as a non-native speaker in Mexico, trying to be informal does not always work well. Native speakers know how to do it, but with non-native speakers it may sound forced. If you are resorting to Stack Exchange, you may have not learned the informal word in the context of the nation, demographic, social circle, etc., in which you intend to use it. I prefer to stay formal. Informality will come out naturally and without pause when you are ready.

Comment: @Paco  well, graciñas for the tip anyway.  I'm thinking of visiting galicia some time this coming year, so I'll investigate ;)

Comment: There's a shortening used in chatting: "grax", but that's not a real word, just a chat-slang that is not used anywhere else, and it's not even correct. I can't think abour any other word because, as ferdoqui says, gracias can be both formal or informal. It's really universal.

Comment: I don't think thanks is actually informal, in fact. Valeu means OK, not thanks.

Comment: @Lambie it depends on context.  Most often "valeu" translates better as "thanks" than "ok", but it depends on the situation.

Comment: Valeu means you are in agreement with what someone talking to you has said. It is an affirmation of some utterance. It does not "mean" thank you per se. In fact, if someone says Obrigado to you and you answer Valeu, it's means: Okay or great.

Comment: @Lambie *technically* "obrigado" means "obligated/obliged", but we translate it as "thank you". In most contexts, *valeu* translates best to "thanks". If I ask someone to pass me something, and they do, I can say "valeu" to express gratitude (informally, probably wouldn't say that to an elder). If I'm short on change at the checkout and my friend lends me 50 cents, I'd say "valeu". Translating that as *OK* makes no sense in English. There are other situations where it's something more like *OK* or *alright?*, but often it means *thanks*. Talking about BP, don't know if this is common in EP.

Comment: Oh please, obrigado translates to thank you. Who's into literalisms?? You are wrong about valeu. I am a native English and Portuguese speaker and a longtime translator and interpreter, fyi. The friend who gives you change and to whom you say Valeu would be better translated as: Great. Not thank you. In any event, Gracias is the only way to say Thank you or Thanks in Spanish. There are, of course, many ways to thank someone with other expressions. In any case, I see no reason to bring Portuguese into this. This is a Spanish forum.

Comment: I have heard "vale" (not confuse with valeu) in Chile and Spain. I use it a lot here in Chile as meaning "ok thank you" or "thanks". As in "A:toma aquí tienes el pedido. B: vale"

Answer (score 18):

I think that *gracias* is the most basic, standard way to say *thank you* in Spanish. If you want more options, you have to seek *upwards*:

- *Muchas gracias* (thanks a lot).
- *Muchísimas gracias* (thank you very much).
- *Se lo agradezco* (I thank you).
- *Se lo agradezco en el alma / de corazón / sinceramente / enormemente / etc.* (I sincerely thank you / from the bottom of my heart / and so on).

Nonetheless, some of the more formal options can be exaggeratedly deformed for comical relief:

- *Agradecido quedo* (I remain [yours], in appreciation).
- *Que Dios te lo pague con muchos hijos* (may God bless you with lots of children). Particularly funny among young people who don't care about having children, of course.

So, I'm afraid that in Spanish if you want more informal ways to say *gracias* you'll have to be a bit creative...

Comment: +1 for the option of using exaggerated formality for comic effect, thanks for your response!

Comment: @Some_Guy ¡[De nada](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2685/12637)!

Comment: :-) Nunca había oído lo de "con muchos hijos". En Colombia es muy frecuente el "Dios se lo pague" o "Dios le pague" pero simplemente hasta ahí. Otra muy frecuente es "mil gracias" y exagerando "un millón de gracias"

Comment: También lo he escuchado con "Mi Dios le pague". De hecho es costumbre, al menos en mi familia, decirlo a quien preparó/sirvió la comida. Y lo de "con muchos hijos" no sabría si me dan las gracias o me desean penurias ;)

Comment: @DGaleano por supuesto, el "Dios se lo pague" también se usa aquí, y es formal. La coletilla de los hijos es la versión, digamos, de broma que he oído usar entre jóvenes aquí (a mí me lo han dicho en más de una ocasión), y siempre entre amigos.

Comment: Can the overly polite ones be used sarcastically as in "well _thanks a lot_ for that."?

Comment: @Mörkö asking for sarcastic ways to say "gracias" could be another great question. ;-) You can just say "gracias" with a sarcastic intonation, or go for the famous "gracias por nada" (thanks for nothing).

Comment: He escuchado decir "gracielas" pero los dudo que alguien te entienda alguien al menos que sea joven.

Comment: the fun thing about "dios se lo pague" has the added advantage that you're not specifying exactly *what* God may dish out to the person (thanks to Chico Buarque for that tip: [en español](https://youtu.be/WsdFvPQj9m4?t=290) ,  [e o original em português](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzWI_JjFBr0).  Quite a clever use of "deus lhe pague" I've always thought. _Disclaimer: I have no idea how good that Spanish translation is._

Comment: Regarding this last comment in Colombia we have a way to clarify that as @MauricioMartinez said before. We frequently say "mi Dios te pague" so even if you have a different god or no god at all it is mine that will pay you :-) I would say that here most of the time we say _gracias_ but "(mi) Dios le pague_ is the second most used.

Comment: "I think that gracias is the most informal way to say thank you in Spanish." I think that is misleading. It is just standard.

Answer (score 9):

In Chile we also say "*te pasaste*" to thank and congratulate. But beware, because in other countries it probably means the opposite ("you have exceeded negatively").

Comment: In Spain we also use it for example when someone gives a great present to us and we think we did not deserve it.

Comment: In Peru you can also say "te pasaste".

Comment: In Mexico I don't think this would go over well, because "te pasaste" is used so much in a negative sense, for example when the soup is inedible because you had a horrible accident with the salt shaker.  So thanks Rodrigo for warning people in other countries.

Comment: @aparente001 I think the implication is probably regional and contextual in Mexico, though. Over where I'm from using *te pasaste* in the context of far exceeding a requirement, either in an action or by means of giving a gift the recipient finds undeserved, it's well understood to be either negative or positive depending on the context

Comment: In that sense, in English, we say: You went out of way [to do x for me]. Whereas, in Spain, it means: You went to far [and were rude, for example].

Answer (score 7):

**Muy amable**

(Mexico at least)

Sometimes this is used in conjunction with "gracias," but it can stand on its own if you have to or want to be especially succinct.  For example, I was a bit disoriented when driving in a strange city recently, pulled over to ask a woman who was standing on the corner chatting on the phone, noticed she was speaking in Spanish on the phone, and asked her in Spanish if I should turn at that corner to get to the bus station.  It was possible I might find that I was blocking traffic, so I only said, "Muy amable."  Where the full version is "Gracias, muy amable," or "Gracias, señora, muy amable." (Roughly equivalent to "Thank you, you're an angel.")  This is not slang, it's gracious speech that anyone can use comfortably.  (Not that I have anything against slang, but you need to know what is and what isn't slang.)

Note: I forgot to include a literal translation of "muy amable": *[That is] very kind [of you].*

**(Esto / Ud.) me ayudó mucho**

This would work in any language.  If you want to show your appreciation for something someone did, or information provided, and you don't want to repeat "thank you" for the umpteenth time, you could say *(This / You) was very helpful [for me].*

Comment: will `me ayudaste mucho` work?

Comment: @nylypej - Sure.  If you want something that fits culturally in Mexico, "muy amable" or a longer, more flowery version, can't be beat.

Answer (score 4):

If Latin American slang is acceptable for your use case, in Chilean Spanish we use "vale" as a very informal "gracias".

Comment: That's cheating.  From my (limited) experiences in Spanish speaking countries, I think I worked out that *vale* means pretty much everything.

Comment: (I'm kidding of course, thanks for the help!)

Answer (score 2):

Here in Mexico we sometimes use *Chido* that also means good, great or funny.

Comment: Hello and welcome to [spanish.se]. This is indeed answering the question, but it would benefit from some further explanation. Could you [edit] adding some examples, references, etc as described in [answer]?

Comment: so would you actually say "chido" to someones as a reply to them doing something?

Comment: @Some_Guy - I believe it's an informal thank-you, given as an off-hand, one-word response.

Answer (score 2):

In certain areas in Mexico, it's common to express gratitude with enthusiasm, in a way that a word for thank you is not explicitly necessary. This would likely be the most vulgar way of saying thank you that is positive and acceptable among people, especially peers.

This is slang and language you would not use in a formal setting or with superiors, but among friends, if someone gives you a gift or brings you something you wanted (especially when it's hard to find or to acquire), you are able to use phrases that congratulate the person who has gotten you said gift for their ability to acquire it.

See, for example:

> ¡Wey, *te la rifas*, me encantan estas galletas!
>   (Here, *te la rifas* is regional slang for something akin to *you're so badass*)

Another answer said it before, but in order to say thank you in ways that are more vulgar than *gracias*, you'll have to be a special kind of creative.

Answer (score 1):

Generally people in Latinamerica just say "Gracias" or "que Dios te lo pague, <s>porque yo no puedo</s>" (may God pay you because I don't have enough to pay for such a big favor) because you don't know how to give back the favor someone has done to you, or if someone has lent you money and you won't be able to give it back.

Another thing people can say is "Dios te bendiga" (God bless you) or "Me fue de mucha ayuda" (it helped me a lot).

Comment: @walen comment is correct. First you should only say "Que Dios te lo pague" or "Dios le pague". Second this is not humorous. Religion is a big part of LA culture and one might think that it is better if god pays you instead of me because you will be better off (given that one believes in god). **Dios le pague** is a perfectly serious form of saying _thank you_

Comment: @walen completamente de acuerdo.

Answer (score 1):

Since the famous Argentine band Soda Stereo gave their last live concert in 1997, it's been rather common in Argentina to use the expression *Gracias totales*, employed by their late vocalist Gustavo Cerati (hear it at the end of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4Sv-2ytWoM) or else [here](https://youtu.be/cOO0_n87ItM?t=10)). It's definitely informal, but it's got the right vintage to sound at least familiar to almost everyone in Argentina, and possibly elsewhere (Soda Stereo was well-known in most of Latin America).